# HTML 5 <a> Tag target="framename" not working with rel="noreferrer"

Tags: html

I'm facing a little issue over here. 
If I set the rel attribute to noreferrer, my target attribute is not working anymore. 
It still opens a new tab if you click on it twice, instead of using the tab created on the first time.


Here some Code:

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.de" target="test" rel="noreferrer">Click me</a></p>
```

jsfiddle not working so look at this one:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target (change the _blank to what ever name you like)

Note: If you first try it without the `rel` and didnt close the opened tab , `target` works well with the `rel`

I've tried it with Chrome and IE.

Is there any reason why this is not working?

Comment: Your example doesn't work with or without the `rel`

Comment: thanks for the reply, I changed the jsfiddle to a w3schools link where my situation is working

Comment: this feature works regardless of you adding `rel="noreferrer"` or not